# What is "sharing filesystem information"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linuxthreads

What's exactly meant by saying "sharing **filesystem information**"? What is in "filesystem information"?

<sub>(This question arose when I saw the `CLONE_FS` flag in some linux headers)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File system information includes root of the file, current working directory, and the umask (file permission). [Represented in the kernel by `struct fs_struct`]

So when you will set CLONE_FS flag, child process and parent process will share file system information.

Now, Take an example: a parent is processing some file, and at that time child process has changed working directory then parent will get problems (if relative path specified) because they share same working directory.

Hope you got your answer.

Comment: What is mean 'root of the file'?

Comment: Means root directory of file.

Comment: chroot(2), chdir(2) will affect while file system is shared between child and parent.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then the working directory and the root of the file must be equal, aren't they? If no then what kind of file(s) we are talking about?

Comment: No no.. root of whole file system (/). chroot(2) can change root folder to a specific path given (but you have to copy some dependencies in that folders).

Comment: Is there anyone who can elaborate this answer? I need a more thorough understanding of this concept.